# How to split String and insert it as new line in the same table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a table Address.

```
create table address(
id  number,
city text,
street text,
house_number text);
```

some times i get city = Berlin, street = xyz and house_number 
instead  3 ,for example,  3-5 or 3-5-7.

i want in this case to split this numbers and crate new line/s so i get :

```
id  city     street  house_number
1. Berlin    xyz      3
2. Berlin    xyz      5
2. Berlin    xyz      7
```

With regard

Andrey

Comment: do you want in MS SQL

Comment: i am working with postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `select unnest(string_to_array(YOUR STRING, '-'));`

it will convert `'3-5-7'`
to:

```
3
5
7
```

Then you can simply run a query that will insert the rows to your table.
See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bf704/1).

Comment: can u give me an example?

Comment: See the added SQLFiddle.

Comment: hi Elad, and if i have more than one city, for example Berlin, Tel-Aviv or Moscow. How can i go threw all of them? in your example you choose select 'Berlin', 'XYZ'...

Comment: Each pair of `(City,Street)` should have it's own string of `house_number`. What you are asking now if I understood you is how to edit the code to support multiple cities. There are many ways to achieve that.. I need to see your original `INSERT` query/function.