# postgresql function insert multiple rows which values are represented by array

Tags: postgresql

I have the table:

```
---------------------------------------
id (integer) | name (character varying)
---------------------------------------
```

I want to insert multiple rows represented by array of character varying. I have the function code:

```
create or replace function add_task_state( TEXT ) returns void as $$  
declare
    _str_states character varying[];
begin       
    _str_states = string_to_array($1,',');
    insert into task_states (name) values ???;  
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

How I can do this?

Comment: I can use this declaration: `create or replace function add_task_state( _states character varying[] ) returns void as $$ `

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `id` is auto assigned?

Try this approach:

```
create or replace function add_task_state( TEXT ) returns void as $$  
begin       
    insert into task_states (name)  (select unnest(string_to_array($1, ','))); 
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

then:

```
select add_task_state( 'h,c,f' )
```

will give:

```
    id name
   ---------
    1   h
    2   c
    3   f
```

It's very similar to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34434805/how-to-split-string-and-insert-it-as-new-line-in-the-same-table/34434940#34434940)

Comment: side note : No need to use `plpgsql` in this case. [this](http://hastebin.com/mofatevuno.pas) is enough

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FOREACH](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) and the function should be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_task_state(TEXT) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
   a text[] := string_to_array($1,',');
   i text;
BEGIN
FOREACH i IN ARRAY a --loop through each element in array `a`
LOOP
  insert into task_states (name) values (i);
END LOOP;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

If your Postgres version is older than 9.1 then you can use

```
FOR i in 1..array_length(a, 1) LOOP
INSERT INTO task_states (name)
VALUES (a[i]);

END LOOP;
```

use : `select add_task_state('value1,value2,value3')`